# Winform Checklistbox Headers/Columns

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-3.5

Is there a way to implement a new column with a header in a checklistbox in vb.net?  I've done a bit of searching, but didn't find much on the topic.  Should I just abandon the quest and use a listview or some other control?

Thanks for any/all help!
JFV

Comment: I don't get it.  Is the checkbox is in a datagrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a ListView with a checkbox column.  You'll have better luck.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation of my suspicions.  Better now than run a foolhardy quest!  Thanks!  -JFV

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is a DataGridView with a checkbox column.

Comment: Another good idea, but I think that the ListView is a better alternative for my data.  Thanks!  -JFV